# Blocking artefacts with DCT decompression Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, compression, computer-vision

I'm attempting to compress an image using DCT in opencv and getting more artefacts on decompression than I expected.

My compression process is:

```
Take DCT of 8x8 blocks in image
Do element-wise division of each 8x8 block by the given quantisation matrix
Round all elements to the nearest whole number
```

My decompression process is:

```
Take 8x8 blocks of the DCT and do element-wise multiplication by the quantisation matrix
Perform an inverse DCT
```

I do this in YCrCb space on each channel and for element-wise division and multiplication I'm using the cv::divide and cv::multiply. For quantisation matrices I'm using the JPEG standard matrices shown here http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-quantization.html (under the heading JPEG Standard). I'm applying the luminance matrix to the Y channel and the chrominance matrices to the Cr and Cb channels.

Finally here are the images:

[image: Before Image]

[image]

Unfortunately I can't share the code otherwise I would. But I will answer any questions people have to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DCT coefficients of an image are signed doubles with negative values. After quantising and rounding the elements I converted the matrix from a CV_64FC3 type to CV_8UC3 expecting the equivalent of a static_cast to be applied to the elements.

However OpenCV when converting from 64F to 8UC zeroed out all negative values resulting in information loss that caused the blockiness.

The solution was apply a static cast converting the double to an unsigned char and writing it into the returned array instead of utilising the opencv convert function.

Comment: So what did you do with the negative values? They just wrap around?

Comment: yep they just wrap around

Comment: How does that not result in massive errors? Or do you also make them negative again when decoding? Or maybe some cosine symmetry property at play...

Comment: The main part of the compression is truncating the fractional component of the DCT amplitudes when decoding I turn them back into a signed number. This was a while ago so I either did unsigned because a byte is technically unsigned and as such bitwise ops are technically undefined behaviour on signed bytes or because I didn't realise there was a CV_8SC3 (or is there? Can't remember)

Answer (score 0):

May be this is how it should look, its possible that you have quantized the coefficients a lot which is leading to this pattern. Such artifacts do arize in jpeg compression when you want to throw away a lot of information for saving more on the size of the image.

Your results look similar to the images shown at the bottom of this wiki page
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

May be you should reduce the quantization level for getting better quality images.

Comment: I was using the JPEG standard matrices for quality level 50. I discovered the solution and I will post the answer shortly (rounding issues).